# How to find out what admin has posted recently on facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, admin

Recently we are facing some issue with our Facebook fan pages, some post are getting posted which are not related to the page so we have to find out what admin is posting what on the FB walls.
It mean there must a be a log that we can see for example
admin1 has posted these ...
admin2 has posted these ...

Is there any way!? maybe an app!
Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook just launched a new feature for Page administrators which will show the exact admin who wrote the post and comment on behalf of the Page.

**Starting Feb. 20, 2014 the names of admins will show next to their posts and comments. This will be visible to anyone with an admin role on your page.**

The new label will be shown on Page activities such as, posting updates (as '**Posted by**'), commenting (as '**Commented by**') and also on scheduling posts(as '**Scheduled by**').

Sources: [**Facebook Page Admins Can Now See Who Exactly Authored Posts And Comments**](http://www.sociobits.org/2014/02/facebook-page-admins-can-now-see-who-authored-posts-and-comments.html) and [**Facebook Help Page**](https://www.facebook.com/help/225783087608655)